# Outlook live spam filter system

Tags: microsoft-outlook, spam-prevention, inbox

I am trying to migrate my personal email from gmail to outlook (the webmail).
So far, easy steps, but I've noticed that the spam filter is very aggressive (or I don't understand it).

Even sending simple text from proton/gmail to outlook goes into **Junk** (considering the outlook account is  freshly made)

Inspecting the header, I've noticed the SPF is passed and other also

```
spf=pass (sender IP is *.*.*.*) smtp.mailfrom=gmail.com; outlook.com; dkim=pass (signature was verified) header.d=gmail.com;outlook.com; dmarc=pass action=none header.from=gmail.com;compauth=pass reason=100
```

So, can  someone explain me the following headers:

X-Microsoft-Antispam-Mailbox-Delivery:

```
abwl:0;wl:0;pcwl:0;kl:0;iwl:0;dwl:0;dkl:0;rwl:0;ucf:0;jmr:0;ex:0;auth:1;dest:J;OFR:SpamFilterAuthJ;ENG:(... some numbers ... );RF:JunkEmail;
```

What does the **auth:1**, what **OFR** stands for and why it has the value : **SpamFilterAuthJ**

Also I've noticed another header: **X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthAs** has the value : **Anonymous** .

Thanks in advance for the explination, any reference or detailed explinations are more than welcomed (so far I didn't find something explicit for the header: X-Microsoft-Antispam-Mailbox-Delivery - I think this is the problem)

Comment: I hope you get some answers.  Been looking for a very long time why outlook decides to classify my messages (sent from seamonkey, aka. thunderbird) as spam.

Answer (score 0):

You could actually copy and paste the contents of a message header into the [Message Header Analyzer tool](https://mha.azurewebsites.net/). This tool helps parse headers and put them into a more readable format.

It could analyze a single "*Microsoft Antispam Header*" like below:
[image]

For more detailed information of this field, you could refer to this article:[X-Microsoft-Antispam message header fields](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/office-365-security/anti-spam-message-headers?view=o365-worldwide#x-microsoft-antispam-message-header-fields)

For the field of "*X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthAs*", as I know, it just specifies the authentication source, and here is the detailed introduction in official document:
[image]

Hope that would be helpful to you :)